# rerun failed test cases within test suite

Tags: robotframework

I am using pycharm terminal to execute test suite

```
robot -d Output --loglevel TRACE TestCases\TC001Suite.robot
```

Within the TC001Suite, there are 10 cases.

I want to rerun failed cases for this test suite only.

I have tried --runfailed but it cannot be executed.

Comment: Can you share the command you tried and the error you got please?

Comment: Why cannot you use --rerunfailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the option -d means that you want to output to directory Output. Maybee your xml file is in different director and when you rerun the test it fails

```
robot -d Output --loglevel TRACE TestCases\TC001Suite.robot
```

Dont change the directory and just specify the name of xml file. The
robot will put the output in your current dir.

```
robot --output original.xml --loglevel TRACE TestCases\TC001Suite.robot    # first execute all tests
robot --rerunfailed original.xml --output rerun.xml --loglevel TRACE TestCases\TC001Suite.robot # then re-execute failing
```

you can then merge the tests. You can read about it in the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#merging-outputs)